# What is date-target-input= "nearest"?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

```
 <div style="display:flex;">
    <div id="{{ 'postStartDate' + $index }}" class="col input-group date pl-0 pr-0" data-target-input="nearest" style="width:170px;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" maxlength="10" placeholder="연도-월-일" data-target="{{ '#postStartDate' + $index }}" data-ng-model="eventPost.postStartDate" data-ng-disabled="eventPost.sameYn === 'Y' || eventPost.alwaysYn === 'Y'">
        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="{{ '#postStartDate' + $index }}" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2">
        <input class="form-control" style="width: 140px !important" type="time" data-ng-model="eventPost.postStartTime" data-ng-disabled="eventPost.sameYn === 'Y' || eventPost.alwaysYn === 'Y'">
    </div>
</div>
```

I use angularJS with bootStrap.
what is data-target-input="nearest" ?
And can I use other properties other than nearest for date-target-input? Then what are the attributes?

I just know data-target-input="nearest" mean

Comment: It's a [custom data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*), and from the name and value we can probably deduce, that this is telling the component to look for the "nearest" input field, to bind its functionality to. (It looks like this is part of https://getdatepicker.com/5-4/Usage/, at least that was my first Google hit for the attribute name. Doesn't appear to be explicitly documented there though.)